# Pig error while while entering simple scripts in hadoop 2 environment

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using hadoop-2.5.1 and pig-0.13.0, and my hadoop cluster running very well. When I try to run simple pig script

```
test = load '/input-data/data10' using PigStorage(',');
```

I am getting an error:

```
2014-11-13 15:41:19,278 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-11-13 15:41:19,279 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.addres
```

Please if any one having solution let me know.

Comment: But it's not an error, it's just info logging. May be loading completed successfully, try to add 'DUMP test;' into your script.

Comment: ok, then I post my suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, it's just an info logging.

If your script does not attemp to perform any action on loaded data and doesn't throw any error, then it probably works fine.

Try to add some actions with `test` variable, for example:

```
DUMP test;
```